# Java code to copy CSV file from one S3 bucket of Dev region to another S3 bucket of Test region

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

My requirement is to write a java that will copy the CSV file present in Test region S3 bucket to Dev region S3 bucket. Can you please help me with the code snippet.

Comment: Java is not for writing a simple file copy app. The Unix Bash fits better to this.

Comment: My requirement is to write a java program to copy the file.

Comment: Plenty of code snippets a search away. If you have code you haven't tried, post that and you'll be more likely to get help.  Right now this looks like homework or a job screening test.